# Query phone numbers, excluding space characters

Tags: search, replace, ldap

Supposing I had a SQL Server table like this..

[image: Somedata]

..and wanted to search for phone numbers containing "345", ignoring any spaces.

In SQL Server, this is easy to do:

[image]

My problem is, I want to do this in an LDAP query, and LDAP queries don't recognize the REPLACE function.

The phone numbers in our Active Directory often contain spaces (or other characters), but I can't work out how to write an LDAP query to simulate the SQL `REPLACE()` function.

So, right now, my query can search for, say, "345" within all phone numbers, but these three characters *must* appear in AD without any spaces between them.

```
Select sn,givenName,mobile,telephoneNumber 
From 'LDAP://OurServerName/DC=global,DC=OurCompany,DC=net' 
Where (mobile='*345*' OR telephoneNumber ='*345*' )
```

Does anyone know how to get LDAP to search, ignoring spaces ?

I have found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040826/ldap-search-on-phone-numbers) which suggest LDAP just copes with this out of the box... but from what I've seen, it doesn't...

(And yes, we want to avoid running a script against Active Directory to remove all spaces from all phone numbers.)

Btw, our company has less than 1500 employees, so the performance of the query shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is what it is.

TelephoneNumber and Mobile use the the Telephone Number syntax (1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.50) and LDAP implementations SHOULD follow [RFC 4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-4.2.30) and use telephoneNumberMatch and telephoneNumberSubstringsMatch BOTH which implement "Insignificant Character Handling". (ie ignoring spaces, "-", etc.) in accordance with [e.123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123)

As far as I know, you will need to run a script or ldif out and parse numbers to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the problem by using as many asterisk symbols **'*'** as you like. Here I mean **exactly one** asterisk between 2 characters (except the beginning and the end).

**Note:** 2 following asterisks won't work.

In your case:

```
Select sn,givenName,mobile,telephoneNumber 
From 'LDAP://OurServerName/DC=global,DC=OurCompany,DC=net' 
Where (mobile='*3*4*5*' OR telephoneNumber ='*3*4*5*' )
```

#### JavaScript approach

```js
const getUsersByPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber) => {
    //...
    const searchDNPhoneNumber = `telephoneNumber=*${phoneNumber.split("")
    .map(character => character + "*")
    .reduce((accumulator, currentCharacter) => accumulator + currentCharacter)}`;
    // Possible result here could be '+*1*2*3*-*4*5*6*-*7*8*'
    //...
    return searchDNPhoneNumber;
}
console.log(getUsersByPhoneNumber("+123-456-789"));
```